# jps command not found while installing hadoop

Tags: hadoop, centos

ian new to centos 7

and iam configuring hadoop 2.7.1 cluster so i need to install openjdk as a requirement
so i installed one  by the command

```
 yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

and java version  command out put is

```
java version "1.7.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.9.0.el7_3-x86_64 u131-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.131-b00, mixed mode)
```

but my problem is that i want to use jps command and it is found in 
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.101-2.6.6.1.el7_2.x86_64

so i iwant to install this rpm and i used the command

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm
 rpm -ivh --nodeps ftp://mirror.switch.ch/pool/4/mirror/scientificlinux/7.0/x86_64/updates/security/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.101-2.6.6.1.el7_2.x86_64.rpm
```

but becuase a newer version of jdk is installed i wasn't able to install this rpm

with the error

```
package java-1.7.0-openjdk-1:1.7.0.131-2.6.9.0.el7_3.x86_64 (which is newer than java-1.7.0-openjdk-1:1.7.0.101-2.6.6.1.el7_2.x86_64) is already installed
```

i don't know if iam using the right way to make jps command works 
what should i do to include jps command

and is it right to install an old release of openjdk i mean 101 when newer one already exists i mean 131

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java-1.7.0-openjdk` contains only the **JRE**. `jps` is part of the openjdk development package. Refer [here](http://openjdk.java.net/install/).

Try

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
```